# how to dynamically get mobile IMEI number in J2me?

Tags: java, java-me, imei

I has developed one j2me mobile application. Now client side want to see the mobile IMEI number.

So I don't know how to get it, I have tried this line `System.getProperty("com.nokia.IMEI");` but it will come null only.

Comment: Check [this article](http://mobilepit.com/10/how-to-get-imei-number-in-j2me-javame.html), Note: You can't read IMEI for all the phone, there are some phones in which using j2me you could read it

Comment: i have seen this article already,i have tried that line using this article only but i didn't get.thanks any other idea?

Comment: Some device needs the app to be signed to access IMEI

Answer (score 4):

Nokia

```
System.getProperty("phone.imei");
System.getProperty("com.nokia.imei");
System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.imei"); //especially for S40  devices

Note: Requires signed MIDlet. S60 3rd edition device does not requires signing to fetch this info.On Series 40 phones this requires that your MIDlet is signed to either operator or manufacturer domain, and this is only available in Series 40 3rd Edition, FP1
```

---

devices and newer.
Sony Ericsson

```
System.getProperty("com.sonyericsson.imei");
```

Samsung

```
System.getProperty("com.samsung.imei");
```

Motorola

```
System.getProperty("IMEI");
System.getProperty("com.motorola.IMEI");
```

Siemens

```
System.getProperty("com.siemens.IMEI");
```

LG

```
System.getProperty("com.lge.imei");
```

Comment: i have seen this article already,i have tried that line using this article only but i didn't get.thanks any other idea?

Comment: System.getProperty("phone.imei");
System.getProperty("com.nokia.imei");
System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.imei"); i have tried these lines...

Comment: For NOKIA Requires signed MIDlet. S60 3rd edition device does not requires signing to fetch this info.On Series 40 phones this requires that your MIDlet is signed to either operator or manufacturer domain, and this is only available in Series 40 3rd Edition, FP1

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the above calls with `System.getProperty(“microedition.platform”)` in order to get a good solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  [GET IMEI FROM J2ME](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Getting_IMEI_and_IMSI_in_Java_ME) this to get imei from different phone