# IMEI REQUEST in J2ME

Tags: java-me

How can I programmatically display the IMEI number of J2ME? I used `System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.imei")`, and it shows it's running but displays nothing. My device is a Nokia 210 model. Is there any code for this model phone?

Comment: Please, take a look at the other options at this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680779/how-to-dynamically-get-mobile-imei-number-in-j2me

Comment: Thank u for reply I tried those method it came ....

Comment: You should delete this question

Comment: This post is give you the brief idea about how to get the IMEI number from device.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968395/how-to-get-imei-for-j2me-supported-all-devices